# Excel Moving duplicate values to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have compiled this code from bit and pieces I have found - I am by no means an expert - more of an eager student - This code works for me but now I need to keep the first occurrence of the duplicate row to stay on the original worksheet and move only the subsequent occurrence(s) to the newly created sheet.

I am willing to redo all the code if needed but would prefer to modify the existing vba for the sake of time

```
Sub moveduplicates

'***************************************************************
'** This proc expects you to select all the cells in a single **
'** column that you want to check for duplicates in. If dup-  **
'** licates are found, the entire row will be copied to the   **
'** predetermined sheet.                                      **
'***************************************************************

Set Rng = ActiveCell

 'Sticky_Selection()
    Dim s As Range
    Set s = Selection

    Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Duplicate Values"
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Duplicate Values").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    s.Parent.Activate
    s.Select 'NOT Activate - possibly more than one cell!

Dim ShO As Worksheet
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim pRow As Integer
Dim c As Range, cTmp As Range
Dim found
Dim Addresses() As String
Dim a() As String
Dim p2 As Integer
Dim tfFlag As Boolean, sTmp As Variant


Set ShO = Worksheets("Duplicate Values") 'You can change this to whatever worksheet name you want                    the duplicates in Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

MsgBox "The cells selected were " & Rng.Address 'Rng1 is all the currently selected cells
pRow = 2 'This is the first row in our output sheet that will be used to record duplicates
ReDim a(0) 'Initialize our array that holds found values

For Each c In Rng1.Cells 'Cycle through each cell in our selected range
ReDim Addresses(0) 'This array holds the cell address for our duplicates.
               'We will reset the array each time we move to the next cell

Now check the array of already found duplicates.
If the current value is already there skip to next value
tfFlag = False
For Each sTmp In a
If CStr(c.Value) = sTmp Or CStr(c.Value) = "xXDeleteXx" Then 'We've already done this value, move         on
    tfFlag = True
    Exit For
End If
Next

If Not tfFlag Then 'Remember the flag is true when we have already located the
                   'duplicates for this value, so skip to next value
    With Rng1
        Set found = .Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues) 'Search entire selected range for value
        If Not found Is Nothing Then 'Found it
            Addresses(0) = found.Address 'Record the address we found it
            Do 'Now keep finding occurances of it
                Set found = .FindNext(found)
                If found.Address <> Addresses(0) Then
                    ReDim Preserve Addresses(UBound(Addresses) + 1)
                    Addresses(UBound(Addresses)) = found.Address
                End If
            Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> Addresses(0) 'Until we get back to the original address

            If UBound(Addresses) > 0 Then 'We Found Duplicates
                a(UBound(a)) = c.Value 'Record the value we found a duplicate for in an array
                'ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1) 'add an empty spot to the array for next value

                'ShO.Range("A" & pRow).Value = "Duplicate Rows for Value " & c.Value & _
                          " in Column " & c.Column & " on original sheet" 'Add a label row
                'pRow = pRow + 1 'Increment to the next row
                For p2 = UBound(Addresses) To 0 Step -1 'Cycle through the duplicate addresses
                    Set cTmp = Rng1.Worksheet.Range(Addresses(p2)) 'we just want to easily get the correct row to copy
                    Rng1.Worksheet.Rows(cTmp.Row).Copy ShO.Rows(pRow) 'Copy form orig to duplicates sheet
                        cTmp.Value = "xXDeleteXx" 'Mark for Delete the original row
                    pRow = pRow + 1 'Increment row counter
                Next p2
                'Row = pRow + 1 'This increment will give us a blank row between sets of duplicates
            End If
        End If
    End With
End If
Next
 'Now go delete all the marked rows

 Do
 tfFlag = False
 For Each c In Rng1
If c.Value = "xXDeleteXx" Then
    Rng1.Worksheet.Rows(c.Row).Delete (xlShiftUp)
    tfFlag = True
End If
Next
Loop Until tfFlag = False
'AutoFit Every Worksheet Column in a Workbook
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Next sht

Application.Goto Rng
   End
   End Sub
```

Thank you very much for your time and consideration

Comment: Can you post an example (image would be fine) of what an example file might look like?

Comment: Your code doesn't assign anything to `Rng1`

Comment: a) Are you always examining full columns of data for duplicates or are subsets of rows a possibility? b) does your block of data have any fully blank rows and/or columns that would create 'islands' of data? c) does your block of data have column labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a scripting Dictionary object to keep track of duplicates:

```
Sub RemoveDups()

Dim c As Range, dict, rngDel As Range, rw As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim shtDups As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range

    Set rng1 = Selection 'assuming you've selected a single column of values
                         '  from which you want to remove dups

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set shtDups = wb.Worksheets.Add( _
           after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
    shtDups.Name = "Duplicate Values"

    With rng1.Parent
        .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlToRight)).Copy _
                 shtDups.Range("A1")
    End With

    rw = 2

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each c In rng1.Cells
        'already seen this value?
        If dict.exists(c.Value) Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy shtDups.Cells(rw, 1)
            rw = rw + 1
            'add row to "delete" range
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = c
            Else
                Set rngDel = Application.Union(c, rngDel)
            End If
        Else
            'first time for this value - add to dictionary
            dict.Add c.Value, 1
        End If
    Next c

    'delete all duplicate rows (if found)
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
        rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim - It looks like your solution worked out of the box - I'll do some mods (read: cut paste job) to unhide columns and size - Thanks a million - You definitely put me over the finish line

Answer (score 0):

Another enthusiastic amateur here!

Not really answering your question, but here is a little function I use for removing duplicate rows:

```
Sub RemoveDupes(TempWB As Workbook, TargetSheet As String, ConcatCols As String, DeleteTF As Boolean)
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Formula As String
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim StartingCol As String
Dim CurrentRow As Integer


     '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '   Remove duplicate rows on a worksheet                                    '
     '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        '   Prerequisites:
        '   - Data needs to start @ A1
        '   - Data has headings in row 1


' determine number of rows to be processed
RowCount = TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' insert a column to hold the calculate unique key
TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
' add a heading
TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Duplication Check"

' insert the unique key formula
For CurrentRow = 2 To RowCount

    ' start the formula string
    Formula = "="
    ' construct the formula
    For Counter = 1 To Len(ConcatCols)
        ' if we are on the last element, dont add another '&'
        If Counter = Len(ConcatCols) Then
            Formula = Formula & AddLetter(Mid(ConcatCols, Counter, 1)) & CurrentRow
        Else
            Formula = Formula & AddLetter(Mid(ConcatCols, Counter, 1)) & CurrentRow & "&"
        End If
        ' Debug.Print Mid(ConcatCols, Counter, 1)'Next
    ' next element!
    Next

    ' insert the newly constructed formula
    TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(CurrentRow, "A").Formula = Formula

' next row
Next

' unfortunately we need to use explicit selection here *sigh*
TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Activate
' to select the range we are going to test
TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Range("A2:A" & TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Select

' clock down the list flagging each dupe by changing the text color
Dim d As Object, e
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each e In Intersect(Columns(ActiveCell.Column), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If e.Value <> vbNullString Then
        If Not d.exists(e.Value) Then d(e.Value) = 1 Else _
            e.Font.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
Next

' if the delete flag is set...
If DeleteTF Then
    ' then go down the list deleting rows...
    For CurrentRow = RowCount To 2 Step -1

        ' if the row has been highlighted, its time to go...
        If TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(CurrentRow, "A").Font.ColorIndex = 4 Then

            TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(CurrentRow, "A").EntireRow.Delete

        End If
    Next

    ' If we are deleting rows, remove the column just like we were never here
    TempWB.Sheets(TargetSheet).Cells(1, "A").EntireColumn.Delete
End If

End Sub

Function AddLetter(Letter As String)
    ' gives you the next letter
    AddLetter = Split(Cells(, Range(Letter & 1).Column + 1).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

When I get a sec I will have a go adapting this to your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

This will search a specified column for duplicates, copying subsequent duplicates entries to `Sheet2` and then remove them from `Sheet1`.

I've used the Scripting Dictionary too but you will need to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" for the code to work as-is. (Adding the reference will help if you want to learn about dictionaries since it adds the Dictionary to Intellitype code completion stuff)

```
Sub Main()

Dim SearchColumn As Integer: SearchColumn = 2 ' column to search for duplicates

Dim Source As Worksheet: Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim Duplicates As Worksheet: Set Duplicates = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim List As Dictionary: Set List = New Dictionary ' used to hold the first instance of unique items

Dim Data As Variant ' holds a copy of the column you want to search
Dim Count As Integer ' hold the size of said column
Dim Index As Integer ' iterator for data
Dim Item As String ' holds the current item

Count = Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, SearchColumn).End(xlUp).Row

Set Data = Source.Range(Source.Cells(1, SearchColumn).Address, Source.Cells(Count, SearchColumn).Address)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' first loop, find unique items and copy duplicates
For Index = 1 To Count

    Item = Data(Index, 1)

    If List.Exists(Item) = False Then
        ' add the item to our dictionary of items
        List.Add Item, Index
    Else
        ' add item to duplicates sheet as its a duplicate
        Source.Rows(Index).Copy
        Duplicates.Rows(1).Insert xlShiftDown
    End If

Next Index

' second loop, remove duplicates from original sheet
For Index = Count To 1 Step -1

    Item = Data(Index, 1)

    If List.Exists(Item) Then

        If Not List(Item) = Index Then
            ' the item is a duplicate and needs to be removed
            Source.Rows(Index).Delete
        End If
    End If

Next Index

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```